# Detect bold in xml file that was originally docx

Tags: xml, python-3.x, docx

I want to extract all bold text from docx file, couldn't do it using python-docx, I saved the file as xml, is there a way to detect the bold text, isn't  because I don't see it anywhere in the file

this sentence is in bold:

```
<cell ptr="0x7f84240911d0" id="16" symbol="9SwCellFrm" upper="15 lower="17"><infos><bounds left="1502" top="2320" width="10517" 
height="1662"/>
</infos><txt ptr="0x7f842408e460" id="17" 
symbol="8SwTxtFrm" next="18" upper="16" txtNodeIndex="70"><infos><bounds left="1610" top="2320" width="10301" height="322"/></infos>
 Some text <Special nLength="0" nType="POR_MARGIN" rText="" nWidth="3534"/>
<Text nLength="49" nType="POR_TXT" nHeight="322" nWidth="6768"/><Special nLength="0" nType="POR_MARGIN" rText=""/>
<LineBreak nWidth="10302"/>
<Finish/></txt>
```

Comment: An XML fragment that doesn't include the namespace definitions from surrounding namespaces is effectively useless.

Comment: What does "couldn't do it using python-docx" mean? would you care to show an attempt?

Comment: Python docx's job is basically to do the parsing that you are trying to do and package it up into a very neat and accessible format. I'm having trouble imagining why you couldn't get it working.

Comment: Docx files aren't showing properly on ubuntu14.04, so I tried going through all nodes and print the bold text. I didn't get much, so I assumed style isn't applied directly, and assumed it would take a lot of time, looking for each and testing. I wanted something like looking through the whole document by style=bold. I converted it to Word 2003 xml, no namespace there

Comment: Do I need to reconsider python-docx, I am a beginner and I am used to get data directly from the web.

Answer (score 3):

A file that "was originally DOCX" may or may not faithfully represent the bold character style because the new XML format may not support bold or the conversion may not preserve the property.

Had you saved the document as **Word XML Document** (recommended) or Word **2003 XML Document** or even **OpenDoc Text** the resulting XML would preserve boldness.  (How you would have gotten the posted XML from a DOCX file is entirely nonobvious.  Your XML is none of these formats.)

For example, "Word XML Document" is a Flat Open Packaging Convention (FOPC) Office Open XML (OOXML) document, where boldness is (at a basic level) represented as follows:

```
<w:r>
  <w:rPr>
    <w:b />
  </w:rPr>
  <w:t>This text is bold</w:t>
</w:r>
```

Note that determining boldness can get more complicated if represented in XML as part of a style rather than directly as a run property.

Comment: I saved it as Word 2003 xml document, and it's not showing any of these tags, maybe because the originally file wasn't converted properly.

Comment: My answer shows the more modern OOXML WordProcessingML format, but at this level, you would recognize the tags and structure as being similar.  What you've posted in your question is not [**Word 2003 XML**](http://schemas.liquid-technologies.com/office/2003/?page=wordnet_xsd.html).   (Thanks to [*Liquid Technologies*](http://schemas.liquid-technologies.com/) for providing the Microsoft Office 2003 XSDs online.  Microsoft wants you to download an EXE (?!) file to access them.)